# Прокрутка memo по мере добавления текста

Tags: delphi

Значит я добавляю в `memo` текст

```
Memo1.Lines.Add('Поиск завершён');
```

А как сделать так, чтобы мемо прокручивалось по мере добавления

Answer (score 1):

Очень аноит такое поведение. Лучше вставлять в начало.

```
Memo1.Lines.Insert(0,'Поиск завершен');
```

Но если очень хочется, то можно так:

```
Memo1.SelStart:=Length(Memo1.Text);
Memo1.SelLength:=0;
SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);
```